# Получение значений элементов массива из регистра ymm0 , содержащего 8 индексов элементов

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Есть массив (размер 100 000), содержащий значения функции типа `float`.
Используется ассемблерная вставка в программу на C++.
В ходе расчета с помощью AVX в регистре ymm записываются 8 значений типа `int`, которые являются индексами элементов массива.

1. Какой наилучший способ (желательно векторный) заполнить другой ymm регистр значениями из массива с заданными индексами?
2. Какой наилучший способ (желательно векторный) инкремента заданных элементов массива?

Comment: загрузить можно прямо с памяти, главное, что бы данные были выровнены, хорошо, если будут по границе 32. Инкримент - пока в голову приходит только загрузить в другой регистр все единички и просто сложить.. И зачем использовать непосредственно ассемблерные инструкции, если есть инстрики?

Comment: а можно по конкретнее про загрузку из памяти?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764016/load-array-of-integers-into-avx-register

Comment: так загружаются 8 элементов, идущих последовательно. а в моем случае это не так

Comment: значит нужно подготовить данные так, что бы они лежали последовательно.

Comment: Можно и не последовательно, но работать будет в разы медленнее это раз, и если не последовательно, то как это два. Исходников не видно в вопросе.